# Python matrix formation

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I want to write a python matrix that looks like:

```
[P1^3,p2^3,p3^3,p4^3 ...]
[p1^2,p2^2,p3^2,p4^2 ...]
[p1^1,p2^1,p3^1,p4^1 ...]
[p1^0,p2^0,p3^0,p4^0 ...]
```

The number of columns and the index of `p` is determined by the input `i` of `pi`

I tried many ways, but it doesn't work.

Someone please help me.

Comment: You tried many ways!? Such as?

Comment: Are you really wanting to perform exclusive or operations on each entry?

Comment: "The number of columns and the index of p is determined by the input i of pi" is confusing to me, can you elaborate/rephrase? Do you mean p(i) not pi?

Comment: @Khalid I don't think it's a good thing to edit such a question. The OP is manifestly someone who considers StackO just as a distributor of answers, making no effort to say hello in his/her first post, to present the problem in a correct manner (what are these several lists one after the other) and to show his/her alleged numerous essays. Moreover, the one letter pseudo doesn't induce the idea that he plans to do anything else than get an answer in a hurry and then to fly away forever. Such a question doesn't deserve to be made nicer, it is substracting a flaw to the eyes of readers

Answer (score 4):

If you really meant `**` and not `^`, you can do this with a single function, `numpy.vander` (for Vandermonde) from the `numpy` library (http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [13]: p = numpy.array([2, 3, 5, 10])

In [14]: numpy.vander(p, 4).T
Out[14]: 
array([[   8,   27,  125, 1000],
       [   4,    9,   25,  100],
       [   2,    3,    5,   10],
       [   1,    1,    1,    1]])
```

The `.T` after the function call transposes the array, since the array created by `numpy.vander` is the transpose of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`[[y^x for y in [p1, p2, p3, p4]] for x in [3, 2, 1, 0]]` is probably what you want.

This expands to

```
[[y^3 for y in [p1, p2, p3, p4]], 
[y^2 for y in [p1, p2, p3, p4]],
[y^1 for y in [p1, p2, p3, p4]],
[y^0 for y in [p1, p2, p3, p4]]]
```

Note that `^` is xor in python.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to get here...

Also, do you mean numpy matrix/array or nested list?